# Decompiling Java packed in exe. Find the zip file in a binary stream?

Tags: java, decompiling

I have a `exe` file that is in fact a very simple java application. I'd like to decompile it and fix some issues, but I'm not sure how can I get the `.jar` data to start the decompiling. I have inspected the file using resource hacker:

[image: screenshot from resource hacker]

Next to tree names, I have written key values using `Courier new` font. My notes use `Arial`. The last key was an XML file from some IDE, originally looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
            <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"
                uiAccess="False" />
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

While none of the data above indicates where the JAR code could be, an experienced programmer could probably know what program was used to pack this, which is why I'm asking you.

Other way to get the data would be some magic to find the `.jar` (which is actually a ZIP, isn't it?) file in the `.exe` binary and crop the `.exe` to get the uncorrupted jar file. But how would I do this? The second part of question title refers to this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, well, 7zip does the trick:

[image: using 7zip, you can "unzip" many .exe files actually]

Once you open the `.exe` file, just extract it:

[image]

You can actually extract many seem-to-be binary files. It's fun :D